# How to switch branches in eclipse without commiting changes

Tags: eclipse, git, branch, git-commit, git-checkout

I've been using GIT for a couple of weeks now and trying to understand how to switch branches without commiting files. This is what I have done.

1. Cloned a git repository and have a local master branch.
2. Created a new local branch (Branch2) which is based on a remote branch.
3. Made changes to 2 files in the master branch.

What I want to do now is switch from master to Branch2.
The changes I made to the master branch are for local dev purposes only and should never be committed.
But when I try to do this in eclipse (i.e I double click on the local branch I try to switch to) it keeps telling me that there are uncommitted changes and I need to commit, stash or reset.

Can anyone tell me how i can make a change to a local file and have git ignore this change so that I don't  get prompted with this message?

Comment: Usually if you have "for dev purposes only and should never be comitted"-files, you have a template file like `foo.bar.dist`, on setup you copy it to `foo.bar` and of course `/foo.bar` is in `.gitignore`. The reason: You _will_ commit it sooner or later, if you don't exclude it explicitly.

Comment: Please make sure you understand "local branches" in and the distributed features of Git. Ongoing development work should be in a local branch. If and once it's ready you can merge/push stuff to a remote. If you don't want to publish, keep it local. You should adhere to "commit early, commit often" as a best practice. Git stash is powerful, but branching is even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the changes to be ever made public you should just commit them in your own feature branch and not on the master branch.
You can create a new branch, give it a name that reflects the changes, maybe prefix is with something like "experimental-" and then commit to that branch before switching to your other branch.

You can use git stash to stash your changes, or use git stash to commit them directly to a new branch as mentioned by Ege Akpinar.

Comment: Some really helpful comments here. Thank you.

Comment: Some really helpful comments here. Thank you. 
So essentially, i shouldn't be making changes to the master branch if i don't want to commit them. I should do this in a new or feature branch.
Therefore, if i create a new branch lets say, MyNewBranch, and I want to incorporate these changes to the master, is it just as simple as commiting the changes in MyNewBranch and then doing a merge i.e.
git commit -a "change description"
git checkout master
git merge MyNewBranch

@PeterSmith

Comment: Yes you can just merge your branch into master. Additionally you can rebase your branch if the master branch has new commits and you want to make sure you don't get merge conflicts.  
Make sure to use `git merge --no-ff` to maintain branch history if you are merging after a rebase.

Answer (score 5):

Note: if you need to stash a work in progress *from Eclipse*, Egit now [supports stash](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.0#Stash_Support):

[image: stash in EGit]

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at git stash. Stash allows you to store uncommitted changes.

Option 1

```
git stash
git checkout -b Branch2
```

Your changes will be stored in git (locally). When you want to re-apply those changes, you will do `git stash pop` and it will apply those changes for you.

Option 2

```
git stash
git stash branch temporarybranch
```

This will take your uncommitted changes to a new branch and keep them there for you. Compared to the previous option, this allows you to keep these branches on the server by pushing this new branch.

Hope it helps

Comment: +1 for `git stash branch <name>` i didn't knew that was possible !